# Need Infinite zooming for my Drawing View which is on UIscrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, zooming

Is it possible to zoom infinite? as i have a floor drawing functionality, i need to zoom even for a small room to be display as larger by implementing infinite zooming. If i'm zooming more than 15 times of original drawing view, drawing is disappearing and displays nothing.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!!

Here is my sample code block:

```
self.scrView.maximumZoomScale=200;
self.scrView.minimumZoomScale=0.5;

#pragma mark ScrollView Deleagte

- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return self.objDrawingView;
}
- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(CGFloat)scale
{
[self.objDrawingView.layer setContentsScale:self.objDrawingView.transform.a*[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]];
    [self.objDrawingView setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are doing the drawing yourself in `drawRect`, it sounds better performance wise (and of course because of your "ignoring bogus layer" message), to have some own values containing the scale and the offset, and respecting this in your drawing code. This way the layer's size will always stay the same and there is no need to draw that huge layer if most of it is outside of the displays bounds.

Of course it shouldn't be a child of the scrollView then, so you need to get the values from `scrollViewDidScroll` as well to calculate your currently visible rect.

Example of the idea:
if the current code in `drawRect` would look like

```
CGContextFillRect( CGRectMake(x,y,width,height) );
```

and you are scaling this by scaling the whole layer, I am suggesting to have a variable containing the current scale and don't scale the whole layer, like:

```
CGContextFillRect( CGRectMake(x* _zoomScale,y* _zoomScale,width* _zoomScale,height* _zoomScale) );
```

or even better use the scale and translate methods on the `CGContext` then your drawing code would be independent from these. The first three lines in `drawRect` should then be:

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -_contentOffset.x, -_contentOffset.y);
CGContextScaleCTM(context, _zoomScale, _zoomScale);
```

make zoomScale and contentOffset a property and set it in the `UIScrollViewDelegate` methods.

Comment: can you please add a bit of code that actually you want to say?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if reading the `transform.a` is the right approach. Maybe better to use the `scale` variable from the method instead.

Comment: yes, even sacle value also same. But the issue is after zooming around 8-10 times of original size, it is not calling drawRect method.

Comment: Also giving the error like: "ignoring bogus layer... "